# Reactjs : import and load external js library minified files put inside src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app

Within my React app

I ve to import some static minified js files.

I ve started to put my js files inside

```
src/assets/mylibraryfiles/js/file1.min.js
src/assets/mylibraryfiles/js/file2.min.js
src/assets/mylibraryfiles/js/file3.min.js
```

Now i wanna load them within my component.

i ve tried to use **Helmet**

So i ve had this :

```
Render() {
  ...

        <Helmet>
          <script src="/assets/mylibraryfiles/js/file1.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="/assets/mylibraryfiles/js/file2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="/assets/mylibraryfiles/js/file3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </Helmet>
}
```

But that doesn't work

Thta seems to not find my scripts files

[image]

i ve tred alos to pass by relative paths `./../../assets...`
Also that fails

**Any suggestions ??**

Comment: What is a problem? Any console errors ? You can always create a script dynamically and append it to the DOM.

Comment: @Noob i ve updated the question , simply that seems to not find the js files

Comment: As someone just mentioned first `</div>` tag shouldn't it be `<div>` ?

Comment: error whil copy paste not more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the js file into the public folder, then import the js file.

in `index.html`

```html
<head>
  <!-- If your application is built via create-react-app -->
  <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/file1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- or custom webpack -->
  <script src="/js/file1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```